# iText Table hangs in adding element to document and generates huge file

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I'm trying to run an example I downloaded along with iText_1.3.5.jar (I need to stick with this version). When I try to run this simple example, process hangs on `document.add(table)` and when I kill the process, a 100MB corrupt PDF file is created. Could someone please help me on this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
Rectangle pageSize = new Rectangle(100f, 18f);
Document document = new Document(pageSize);
    try {
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("test.pdf"));

        document.open();
        Table table = new Table(1,1);
        table.addCell("text"); 
        document.add(table); //culprit

    } catch (DocumentException de) {
        System.err.println(de.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.err.println(ioe.getMessage());
    }

    document.close();
}
```

Comment: 1.3.5?  Was that written before or after *the invention of fire*?!  Ye flippin gods man.  What curse do you labor under that would require you to use software that is at least partially *fossilized*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I chose to use 'PdfPTable' class instead of 'Table' and it's working fine without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Does the latest version of IText hang? 1.3.5 is a pretty old version

Comment: Have you tried the IText mailing list which is where the IText developers hang out?

Comment: Thanks for the direction. I'll post it there too.